# Dataset of Sentences Classified by Type?

Tags: data-request, nlp, language, russia

Where can I find a labeled dataset of sentences classified by type (interrogative and declarative)? I'm particularly lookings for Russian sentences, but other open and labeled datasets of other languages will be helpful.

Basically, I need a dataset of sentences, which not consist only of question words, and sometimes don't have a question mark. It will be good, if dataset will have some declarative sentences with question mark (e.g. *'The bus has already left?'*)

Comment: *'The bus has already left?* still seems like a question to me. You are asking for confirmation that the bus has already departed.

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes, the point is that this sentence is a question, but in an unusual form, so perfect dataset should also contain such sentences.

Comment: Can't you then classify sentences yourself if they end in question mark?

Comment: My point is your question text: don't give that as an example of a declarative sentence. Please [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark Weisser's SPAADIA corpora consist of 35 transactional dialogues annotated at the sentence-level with function/mood (declarative, interrogative, imperative, etc)

He's also got a nice annotation guideline for expanding on this schema.
[martinweisser.org/index.html#spaadia_v02](http://martinweisser.org/index.html#spaadia_v0)