# Where is a large list of declarative and imperative sentences

Tags: data-request, language

For a project I need a bunch (+500 each) grammatically correct sentences (English) that are declarative (basic or simple), imperative (command), and interrogative (question) (sorted by group or separate). Getting a list of questions was fairly easy but getting the declarative and imperative sentences are much harder. I've gone through just about ever grammer site and copied and pasted their examples sentences and came up with few of my own. But I only got about 200 max for each. So is there a large list of these sentences (preferably not combined) that I could use or some post where everyone that wants to post short list of these sentences (I've seen some posts on other sites asking for examples, but like a really large on of these)? Sorry if this is the wrong place for a question of this sort.

Comment: duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11024/1511

Comment: @philshem The link but that contains a lot "yes"s, "no"s, and other non sentence data along with many grammer errors. Also they don't seem have a way to detect if they are declarative or imperative sentences. But it's really interesting and I might be able to manually copy and paste a few sentences. Thanks for the link.

Comment: The answer to that other question may not exactly satisfy your needs, but it is still the same question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dataset of Sentences Classified by Type?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10785/dataset-of-sentences-classified-by-type)

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Sorry I forgot, editied